# Access Sharepoint 2007 (MOSS) Environment from Sharepoint 2010 Environment using C# Console Application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have two set of environment, one where sp 2007-moss is running and other where SP 2010 is there.I want to access, specifically copy a file from a site in moss environment to a site in SP 2010 environment through source and destination URL using C# console application running in SP 2010 environment. How it's possible?

Answer (score 1):

MOSS 2007 don't offer any client object model.
You can use built-in web services ([Web Services Access](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb862916%28v=office.12%29.aspx)), or you can write your own for using server side code remotely via web methods.

There is an article about downloading files from SharePoint 2007 document library remotely via web services: [How to download files from a SharePoint document library remotely via Lists.asmx webservice (SPS 2003/ MOSS 2007)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sowmyancs/archive/2007/09/15/how-to-download-files-from-a-sharepoint-document-library-remotely-via-lists-asmx-webservice-sps-2003-moss-2007.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Can you please add some example regarding how to do it using web service access method

Comment: I'm added link to article with example of downloading files from MOSS 2007 remotely.